# Como carregar páginas HTML no modal do bootstrap?

Tags: html

Tenho as seguintes páginas html:  **produto1,**   **produto2**, e  **produto3**

Em cada página desses produtos, eu tenho um botão para ver mais detalhes dessas respectivas páginas

Quando eu clicar nesses botões eu gostaria de abrir seu respectivo html em um modal, `id=#myModal` para cada página diferente, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não entendi qual é a intenção.

Comment: abrir uma página em um modal do bootstrap, um exemplo tá nesse site aqui, nos produtos: http://www.mirandabombas.com.br/

Comment: Sugiro que reformule a sua pergunta para que seja entendida pela comunidade. Coloque os códigos que você já desenvolveu e mostre qual é a sua dúvida de forma bem clara.

Comment: Até onde eu vi, o modal foi preenchido com conteúdo no próprio HTML, e não uma página carregada dentro dele, não entendi esse href.

Comment: Não tem nada de mais nesse modal o que tem dentro dele é mais código html. css, e alguns com um carrossel http://prntscr.com/nifn2l

Comment: acabei de editar a pergunta, qualquer coisa me falem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode usar um iframe dentro do modal, vou deixar o link de como fazer isso.
Por mais que seja possivel, eu não recomendo o uso de iframes, seria melhor colocar o html puro dentro do modal.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565716/load-iframe-in-bootstrap-modal